I am trying to connect two nextjs applications runnig on two different ports using rewrites, one is a docker container and the other isn't
I get a not found page when I ran the app without ngrok https url for the docker container which is my destination, but nothing else changes when I use the ngrok https url for the said destination.
For starters, I used ngrok to enable https on the docker container's url but that didn't work. Here is my config:
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: 'http://localhost:3000',
        destination: '/ngrok url for docker',
      },
     {
        source: 'http://localhost:3000',
        destination: '/ngrok url for docker',
      },
    ]
  }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It looks like you’re trying to set up URL rewrites for your application but are encountering issues with the configuration. Here are a few things to check and adjust:

Correct URL Format: Ensure that the destination URLs are correctly formatted. They should include the full ngrok URL, including the protocol (https://).
Unique Rewrites: Each rewrite rule should have a unique source and destination. Your current configuration has duplicate entries. Here’s a revised version :



async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/api/:path*',
      destination: 'https://your-ngrok-url/api/:path*', // Replace with your actual ngrok URL
    },
    {
      source: '/another-path/:path*',
      destination: 'https://your-ngrok-url/another-path/:path*', // Replace with your actual ngrok URL
    },
  ];
}



Make sure ngrok is running and the URL is accessible. You can verify this by visiting the ngrok URL in your browser.

Here is a link to the exact problem link. In the mean time I am using redirects.
